# Batch for loop and delete certain folders

Tags: batch-file

**My goal:**
Create a program that creates a folder `A_5`, iterates over existing folders (`A_1`, `A_2` ... `A_4`) and copies `.txt` files from them to the newly created one (`A_5`). Then it should delete all the folders excluding `A_5`. `A_5` should be created in the same directory as other folders.

**My solution:**

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Users\1\Documents\R_scripts\bat-files\A_MAIN
if not exist "C:\Users\1\Documents\R_scripts\bat-files\A_MAIN\A_5" mkdir C:\Users\1\Documents\R_scripts\bat-files\A_MAIN\A_5
for /D %%G in ("A*") do (
    xcopy %%G\*.txt C:\Users\1\Documents\R_scripts\bat-files\A_MAIN\A_5 /y
    if %%G NEQ "A_5" del /s /q %%G
)
```

**Problem:** It creates a folder and copies all `.txt` files to `A_5`, however it also deletes all the folders, despite `%%G NEQ "A_5"`. I've tried logging all the names with `echo >> "C:\Users\1\Documents\R_scripts\bat-files\logging.txt" %%G` and they turn out to be strings as expected, i.e. `A_1`, `A_2` and so on. What can be the problem here? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You are comparing apples with sea cucumbers. `if %%G NEQ "A_5" del /s /q %%G` means you are doing `if this == "this" do something` does `this` and `"this"` look alike? :). additionally, no need to do `if exist` just do `mkdir.... >nul 2>&1`

Comment: …to elaborate on Gerhard's correct and amusing comment: `if` takes everything literally, even quotation marks, so `if "%%~G" neq "A_5"` or `if not "%%~G"=="A_5"` will do the trick; the [`~`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) ensures that potential quotes are removed before explicitly surrounding the string with `""` in order to avoid doubled quotation. By the way, you should in general quote all paths to avoid issues with white-spaces and other special characters…